# Linux convert whole number to an amount field

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple request but can't find anything on the web about it.

this is for Linux bash scripting:

var1=123456

I want to output to look like:

1,234.56 as an amount field ( always 2 decimal)

I tried different variations printf but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: `echo "$var" | rev | sed -E 's/(..)/\1./;s/([^.]{3})/\1,/g;s/,$//' | rev` :)

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like converting a number into *currency* format. Consider the following `printf` approach:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%'.2f\n" ${var1%??}"."${var1:(-2)}
```

The output:

```
1,234.56
```

---

`'` sign within `"%'.2f\n"` format provides decimal conversion

I should note that the above depends on your current `LC=ALL`/`LC_NUMERIC` locale variable(implying decimal point, thousands group separator)

Comment: `var1=123456; printf "%.2f" $var1 | xargs -0 printf "%'.2f\n"` outputs with my bash 4.2.8: `123,456.00`.

Comment: I also get the same output as Cyrus with Locale en_US.UTF-8. I tried also to apply LC_ALL=C in front of the very first printf but same result.

Comment: apologies, I forgot something. Fixed. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I suggest to prefix your answer with `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 `.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex solution that seems to work up to 999,999.99 , keeping always 2 decimal digits:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"1"
1
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"12"
12
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"123"
1.23
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"1234"
12.34
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"12345"
123.45
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"123456"
1,234.56
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"1234567"
12,345.67
$ perl -pe 's/(.*?)(.{1,3})(.{2}$)/\1,\2.\3/;s/^,//' <<<"12345678"
123,456.78
```